# query.whereKey returns nil for relation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

**Xcode 7 beta 4**

I have `Poem` class from **Parse.com**. In my Parse `User` class I have column `likedPoem` which is a relation to the class `Poem`

I only have one record in my `Poem` class. I added it previously to the `likedPoem` in my code:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"Poem")    
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(poemParseObjectId!) {

      (poem: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil && poem != nil {

            let user = PFUser.currentUser()
            let relation = user!.relationForKey("likedPoem")
            relation.addObject(poem!)
            user!.saveInBackground()
        }
}
```

I can see it in Parse Data Browser

Now I want to check if current user liked the poem that I am showing:

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
let relation: PFRelation = user!.relationForKey("likedPoem")
let query = relation.query()!
query.whereKey("likedPoem", equalTo: poem!)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (poem1: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
              print(poem1)          
 }
```

It prints `nil`

If I change it to check what is in that column:

```
<...>
//query.whereKey("likedPoem", equalTo: poem!)
 query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
     (poem1: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
               print(poem1!)
               print(poem!)


}
```

I can see that `poem1!` is `not nil` and it is actually has all the same properties values as `poem!`

**Question:** Why `query.whereKey("likedPoem", equalTo: poem!)` return me `nil` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

I think I see the problem with your code. `likedPoem` is the relation column in your parse table. You are retrieving it correctly using `relationForKey`, but after you retrieve it, the query constraints are incorrect. You cannot put constraints on this column, because the column is a relation. Think of it has a subset of the `Poem` class. You are now querying a subset of the `Poem` class, and any constraints put on the query must pertain to columns in the `Poem` class.

So, for what you want to do, remove the `query.whereKey("likedPoem", equalTo: poem!)` constraint, and check the result against the poem object that you are displaying.

Now, this only works because you have one `Poem` object, and you are calling `query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock`. In the future (if the user likes more poems), you are going to have to modify this a little and change it to `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` so you can retrieve an array of all of the liked poems, then you can check to see if the shown poem is in that array.

On a side note, I have used parse in a lot of my apps, and I have learned that relations are not always the best thing to use, and when you use them it can be tricky figuring out what class to put them in to optimize your queries. This is why you should always keep your queries in mind before determining your app's schema. Here are some other ways you can accomplish what you want to do:

- You can put a constraint on your current query, such as `query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: poem!.objectId)`. This will check the objectId's of all of the poem objects in the relation, and compare it to the objectId of the displayed poem. Now, here you can use `countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` instead of retrieving the objects. You technically do not need to retrieve all of the poems (because you already have the one you want), you just want to know if it is in the relation, so `count` will do this perfectly.
- Use an `Array` of `Poem` objects instead, as sometimes it can be easier for checking if your object is contained in it.
- You could also move the relation/array to the `Poem` class. Now, it would be a relation/array of users who liked the poem, it accomplishes the same thing, but it all depends on your preference and if it works with all of your queries (finding all of the user's liked poems, finding the users who liked a single poem, find out out how many likes a poem has)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `whereKeyDoesNotExist("key")` method from Parse for querying data that the key belonged to it is missing.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why the OP is getting nil and why your solution does not return nil.

Comment: I'm not sure.  I just re-ran some code to verify that I was getting the results as expected.  I ran a PFQuery with a non-nil key and the query did not return any results.  When I ran the same query after making the data in Parse (undefined) an object was returned.  I would further investigate the Parse API Doc for reference or check out the GitHub page.  The code is open source now.